# How to decouple client class with a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template class:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T val;
    Node *next;
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
     T data1_;
     T data2_;
     vector<Node<T> >  vi_;
};
```

Now I want to serialize `MyClass` to disk using different method. For example, using raw c system call write/read or c++ `fstream` , or other approach.

I introduce another template parameter to do that:

```
template<typename T,typename SerializerTrait>
class MyClass
{
     T data1_;
     T data2_;
     vector<Node<T> >  vi_;

     void save()
     {
           SerializerTrait::save(data1_);
           SerializerTrait::save(data2_);
           SerializerTrait::save(vi_);
     }

};


//serializer
template <typename>
class RawC 
{
     static FILE *f;
     static void save(T t){fwrite(&t,sizeof(t),1,f);}
     ...
}

template <typename>
class StreamCPP
{
     static fstream *f;
     static void save(T t){*f<<t);}
     ...
}
```

It can work. But it seems not elegant.

Strategy pattern is a good solution, but template function cannot be virtual.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Split serialization / deserialization from your model. Its generally not good practice to mix them. I would propose to write a template class `template<typename T> Serializer` with a static method called `save` (similiar to your `RawC` and `StreamCPP` classes) and then use template specialization to implement it for every class you need to be serializeable. Another approach would be the common `DAO` classes / interfaces in conjuction with a `DAOManager` providing access (that would be the more OO / java like approach).

Comment: Look at how iterator traits work, the trait is a separate struct that you specialise for your own iterators. Your "MyClass" would just consult that struct when it needs to do whatever. Rather than passing in a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    template <class SERIALIZER>
    void save()
    {
        SERIALIZER::save(data1_);
        SERIALIZER::save(data2_);
        SERIALIZER::save(vi_);
    }
    //or with serializer instance
    template <class SERIALIZER>
    void save(SERIALIZER & s)
    {
        s.save(data1_);
        s.save(data2_);
        s.save(vi_);
    }

    virtual void save(SerializerDetail * s)
    {
        s->save(this);
    }

};

class SerializerDetail
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void save(T * p)
    {
        p->save<SomeSerializer>();//use the first two save functions
        //or
        p->save(SerializerInstance);//or this of you want it

    }
};
```